# the curious case of disappearing decimals

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with disappearing decimal places when I put them into arrays and then pasting them out again. not sure why this is happening at all. any soluntions?

an example below:

excel:

```
     A               B 
1    Input           $213,213,132,135,654.00 <--format: Accounting
2    =B1/1000000     $213,213,132.14         <--format: Accounting
3    output          $213,213,132,135,700.00 <--format: Accounting
```

Code:

```
Sub test()
Dim ar() As Variant

ReDim ar(1)
ar(1) = Cells(2, 2).Value

ar(1) = ar(1) * 1000000

Cells(3, 2) = ar(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Dim ar() As Double` instead

Comment: tried, same results

Comment: Excel is dividing a number with no decimal places and then VBA is multiplying the result by the same amount, reversing the original action and theoretically getting you back to where you began, which is a number with no decimal places. What I don't get is when I replicate it, `B3` ends up as `213,213,132,135,654.00` not `213,213,132,135,700.00`

Comment: i've been testing as well. apparently if i format the cells to currency or accounting, the rounding issue occurs. if it's plain numbers, then the decimal issue disappears.

Comment: is there a way around this while having my cells formatted as accounting?

Comment: Got it, writing up the answer now... But not sure its the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

213213132135654.00 / 1000000 =  213213132.135654

You provided the answer when you mentioned that it only does it when formatted as accountancy. Accountancy works to four decimal places only making the result 213213132.1357, when when multiplied gets to the non-matching 213213132135700.00.

As to a fix, I would suggest either using rounding to 4 decimal places in all formula or do the math in another worksheet as numbers and then present the results on your main worksheet as accountancy.

Comment: haha, kinda realized that as well. for a workaround to this i just added to the vb code. 1) change all the formatting in the range to "general" using .NumberFormat  2) after i'm done with the rest of my codes, change the formatting back to "accounting"